# Python - Access Json value by another value

Tags: python, json

```
folders_list = {
   "folders": [{
   "id": "866699",
   "name": "Folder1",
    "files_count": 0,
    "size": "0",
    "has_sub": false
    }, {
    "id": "866697",
    "name": "Folder2",
    "files_count": 0,
    "size": "0",
    "has_sub": false
  }]
```

I need to get the folder id knowing the folder name. I thought that I could convert the json into a python dictionary and do

```
folder_id = [f['id'] for f in folders_list if f['name'] == 'Folder2'][0]
```

But Python doesn't let me convert it into a dictionary because it doesn't recognize "true" and "false" values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) library can handle `false` and `true` in the data:

```
import json

json_str = """
{
   "folders": [{
   "id": "866699",
   "name": "Folder1",
    "files_count": 0,
    "size": "0",
    "has_sub": false
    }, {
    "id": "866697",
    "name": "Folder2",
    "files_count": 0,
    "size": "0",
    "has_sub": false
  }]
}
"""

data = json.loads(json_str)
folders_list = data['folders']
folder_id = [f['id'] for f in folders_list if f['name'] == 'Folder2'][0]
print "folder_id = %s" % folder_id
```

**Output**

```
folder_id = 866697
```